# How to change the regex so it match function calls in the string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to add optional property access expressions in the string, including function calls.

For example, for each input in the array, the output should be like in the comment.

```
const inputs = [
  'foo', //foo
  'foo.bar', //foo.bar
  'foo.bar.baz', // foo.bar?.baz
  'bla.some()', // bla.some?.()
  'bla.bar.you()', // bla.bar?.you?.()
  'account === prop.account.id', // account === prop.account?.id
  '{ myclass: foo.bar.baz }', // { myclass: foo.bar?.baz }
];
```

So to do that I create a regex: `/(\w+)\.(?!\?)/g`, which mean after a word with `.` match the next prop add add `?` using `replace` method:

```
const input = "foo.bar.baz.you";
const output = input.replace(/(?<=\w+\.)(\w+)\.(?!\?)/g, "$1?.");
console.log(output); // foo.bar?.baz?.you
```

it works for property access only and I want to add also for function calls: `bla.some()`

```
const inputs = [
  'foo', //foo
  'foo.bar', //foo.bar
  'foo.bar.baz', // foo.bar?.baz
  'bla.some()', // bla.some?.()
  'bla.bar.you()', // bla.bar?.you?.()
  'account === prop.account.id', // account === prop.account?.id
  '{ myclass: foo.bar.baz }', // { myclass: foo.bar?.baz }
];

inputs.slice(0, 20).forEach((f) => {

  const output = f.replace(/(?<=\w+\.)(\w+)\.(?!\?)/g, '$1?.');
  console.log(output);
});
```

How I can change that regex so it match also to function calls?

Comment: Smells like an X/Y problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement) which will be invoked after a match has been performed to check if it matches interim property (`.prop.`) or a function call (`.func()`):

```js
const inputs = [
    'foo', //foo
    'foo.bar', //foo.bar
    'foo.bar.baz', // foo.bar?.baz
    'bla.some()', // bla.some?.()
    'bla.bar.you()', // bla.bar?.you?.()
    'account === prop.account.id', // account === prop.account?.id
    '{ myclass: foo.bar.baz }', // { myclass: foo.bar?.baz }
];

inputs.slice(0, 20).forEach((f) => {
    const output = f.replace(/(?<=\w+\.\w+)(\.|\(\))/g, function(m) {
        return '?' + (m == '()' ? '.' : '') + m;
    });
    console.log(output);
});
```